# How can I validate student_name that so that only alpha-characters can be entered in it?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

How can I can validate that the `student_name` column in the `student` table can only have alpha-characters entered into it?

Answer (score 3):

If "only alpha-characters" means only the upper and lowercase letters A-Z, you can use a `CHECK` constraint that checks whether there are non-alpha characters

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  create table student (
  2    student_name varchar2(100),
  3    constraint chk_student_name check( student_name = regexp_replace( student_name, '[^[:alpha:]]', null ))
  4* )
SQL> /

Table created.
```

This allows you to insert `student_name` values that are purely alphabetic

```
SQL> insert into student values( 'JustinCave' );

1 row created.
```

But raises an error if you insert something non-alphabetic like a space

```
SQL> insert into student values( 'Justin Cave' );
insert into student values( 'Justin Cave' )
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.CHK_STUDENT_NAME) violated
```

If you want to allow spaces along with the alphabetic characters, you can modify the regular expression

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  create table student (
  2    student_name varchar2(100),
  3    constraint chk_student_name check( student_name = regexp_replace( student_name, '[^([:alpha:]|[:space:])]', null ))
  4* )
SQL> /

Table created.

SQL> insert into student values( 'Justin Cave' );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into student values( 'Justin Cave1' );
insert into student values( 'Justin Cave1' )
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.CHK_STUDENT_NAME) violated
```

Comment: it is working when i entered record using sql plus but how can i implement it in oracle forms?? i want to show an alert on error..plz help

Comment: @sajid - Constraints are enforced regardless of the front end.  If you attempt to insert an invalid string through Oracle Forms (or a Java app or any other type of application), you'll get an error.  You can either display the error to the user or you can catch the error in an exception handler and display a different message.

Comment: Simply go to properties of textbox and set data type = alpha then right click on this item and go to trigger on-error trigger and write the code message('Wrong input'); message('wrong input');

Answer (score 0):

you might be looking for check constraints

syntax might be something like the following inside the create table command:

```
... CHECK REGEXP_LIKE (students_name, '^([:alpha:]|[:space:])*$'), ...
```

examples i've found on the web so far:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp

http://psoug.org/reference/regexp.html

Comment: SO is not really a link farm. Are you actually going to answer the question?

Comment: @Ben as far as i can see nobody suggested check constraints before i did, so where is your problem? do i have to build him a 100% perfect working solution? well if i could i maybe would, but i help as good as i can instead of blaming others. the only point i agree with you is the "link farm" thing ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Oracle's [REGEXP](http://www.regular-expressions.info/oracle.html) function to do it.